# Notation in the probability distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, notation, random-variables

Suppose that a random variable $X$ has a gamma distribution with the shape parameter, $\alpha$, and the scale parameter, $\beta$, i.e., $X \sim \mathrm{Ga}(\alpha, \beta)$.
It is well known that $\mathrm{Ga}(1, \beta)$ is the same as an exponential distribution, $\mathrm{Ex}(\beta)$.

Which is appropriate, 
$\mathrm{Ga}(1, \beta) = \mathrm{Ex}(\beta)$
or $\mathrm{Ga}(1, \beta) \stackrel{d}{=} \mathrm{Ex}(\beta)$ ?

Comment: I removed the [tag:probability-theory] tag. Please avail yourself of the tag summaries when choosing tags.

Comment: $\mathrm{Ga}(1, \beta) = \mathrm{Ex}(\beta)$, since it is a genuine equality.

Comment: Dear Will, Thank you for your comment.